# SharePoint: Custom rendering of a list with JSLink. Throws "undefined"

Tags: sharepoint, undefined

I have a problem, the output for me throws a "undefined" for all my fields except Title.

Here is my code:

```
(function () {

    if (typeof SPClientTemplates === 'undefined')
    return;

 var overrideContext = {};

 //overrideContext.BaseViewID = 1;

 //overrideContext.ListTemplateType = 101;

 overrideContext.Templates = {};

 overrideContext.Templates.Header = "My Custom Rendering News View";

 overrideContext.Templates.Item = customItem;

 SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);

 })();

function customItem(ctx) {

 var htmlTest = "Test: " + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + " " + ctx.CurrentItem.Byline + " " +       ctx.CurrentItem.Modified + " " + ctx.CurrentItem.RollupImage;

 return htmlTest;

}
```

And the output is: 
"Test: News Archive undefined undefined undefined"

Do you guys know what the problem is? I know that the fields Title, Byline, Modified and RollupImage exists in the view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I will fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields aren't called Byline and RollupImage in SharePoint.

They are called: ArticleByLine and PublishingRollupImage.

Also, the actual fields (Byline and Rollup image) need to be included in the view.

Answer (score -2):

Try to replace this code

```
overrideContext.Templates.Item = customItem;
```

with this one

```
overrideContext.Templates["Item"] = customItem;
```